# Trying to order Flask SQLAlchemy object by function

Tags: python, flask, sql-order-by, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a Flask Application that has Categories, Threads, and Posts. I would like to sort the Categories by the most recent post within each.

My Category model has the following function which correctly finds the timestamp of the most recent post:

```
def last_post_time(self):
    last_time = Post.query.join(Thread,Thread.id==Post.thread_id).filter(
        Thread.category_id == self.id).order_by(
        Post.timestamp.desc()).first().timestamp
    return last_time
```

To order this, I would like to run something like:

```
categories = Category.query.order_by(Category.last_post.desc()).paginate(
    page, current_app.config['CATEGORIES_PER_PAGE'], False)
```

Unfortunately, I think this is meant to work on columns rather than the result of functions.

I tried [following this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) in order to make a hybrid property that could be ordered, but I haven't had any luck yet.

I honestly don't really know what I'm supposed to do beyond just adding a @hybrid_property decorator above the last_post_time() class function.

How do I modify the last_post_time function so that my order_by query will work on it?